# cargar archivos al proyecto web

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hola espero se encuentren bien recurro a ustedes haber si pueden ayudarme con este problema, en el directorio de mi proyecto web en la ruta `"WEB-INF/Classes"` tengo una carpeta llamada "txt" y dentro de ello estoy intentando guardar un archivo txt desde cualquier navegador, pero aun no he podido lograr este objetivo, estuve usando este código dentro del Servlet.

```
URL ruta_archivo = getClass().getResource("/txt/"+Nombre_Archivo);
File archivo = new File(ruta_archivo.getFile());
```

Pero por lo que veo esto solo es para encontrar el archivo dentro del directorio del proyecto, mas no para almacenar archivo (eso creo yo), ¿diganme es posible hacer lo que quiero, hay alguna otra forma?.

**Espero sus respuestas, muchas gracias.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, tienes un .txt que descargas de un formulario por ejemplo y quieres guardarlo en tu aplicación, concretamente en classes/txt.
Yo te doy una solución para guardarlo en una carpeta que sea accesible por todos los servlets o jsp del proyecto con un ServletContext. Te pego el código con los comentarios para que lo adaptes a tus necesidades.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // archivo '.txt' recuperado de un formulario
    Part filePart = request.getPart("fileUpload");
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // archivo donde lo vamos a guardar, es decir, vamos a hacer una copia del archivo .txt
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    //System.out.println(context.getRealPath(""));
    File toFile = new File(context.getRealPath("/copy.txt")); // nombre que le doy a la copia 'copy.txt'
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = fileContent.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    fileContent.close();
    out.close();

}
```

Por supuesto que dentro de la ruta a la que accedes con `context.getRealPath("/copy.txt")` puedes crear las carpetas que quieras y modificas el parámetro String según tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias @oscar me funciona de maravilla, solo dos preguntas para salir de duda, si me puedes responder un favor, el primero: `byte[] buf = new byte[1024]` `1024`¿es el tamaño que tiene el archivo verdad, puede ser modificado por uno mas alto o bajo?; y el segundo: `out.write(buf, 0, len)` se que el `buf` es donde se almacenan los bytes y el `len` el tamaño que debe leer, pero el `0` me podrías explicar un favor que significa, que pasa si pongo otro número. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Hola Daniel, respecto 1024 es el tamaño que le doy yo al buffer porque no se el tamaño real del archivo pero por supuesto que lo puedes modificar, respecto a los parámetros del metodo write, el segundo es el desplazamiento para iniciar la lectura del buffer pero puedes empezar mas adelante si lo deseas. Lo normar es empezar en cero logicamente pero habrá situaciones que necesites empezar en otro punto..